# typo3: Page Render broken, after adding bootstrap grid element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typo3

I installed bootstrap_core and gridelements and this seems to do what I want it to do (giving me the option to make a content-element into 2,3 or 4 columns), but each time I insert a grid element, the rendering fails (??) and the CMS returns a blank page.

- Is there a log of the page rendering? I need to find a clue to what is going wrong.
- Am I doing the whole bootstrap+typo3 thing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to answer all questions of the type 'Where did my PHP rendering process get a hickup?' is XDebug. Install XDebug onto your dev machine and then just load the problematic page with &XDEBUG_TRACE=1 appended to the URL. You will get a nice trace of exactly what happened and where.

You need to setup XDebug tracing in the configuration of XDebug but I have no doubt you will figure that one out from the manual.